# How do I make a good quality drawing look like a low quality screenshot from 90's TV in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-quality, filter

Yeah hi, I was wondering how I could get my images to look like they were shown on 90's TV or were recorded to a VHS and ripped into a digital file. Examples shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image][image][image][image]

I'd like to utalize this effect for a flyer/gigposter I'm making.

Comment: ...save the file as a .gif

Comment: google vhs effect photoshop tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Usually people want to up the resolution from the low res images. But I think you are looking for this... :) http://mikeyjam.buzznet.com/user/journal/12237761/tutorial-getting-vhs-tv-effect/

Comment: Please describe the process. If that link goes down then your answer won't be useful any longer.